# Elegant way to add variable to nested lists in R

Tags: r, list, nested

I get nested lists from a third party with occasionaly missing fields in it (because some are optional). I need to store all data in a single dataframe.

Hence my need is to find an elegant way to force the format of each nested list, so that I can then unlist everything in a single dataframe.

Let consider this list :

```
my.list <- list(list(col1=1, col2=2, col3=3),
                   list(col1=1, col2=2),
                   list(col2=2, col1=1),
                   list(col1=1, col2=2, col3=3, col4=4))
```

I want that **each nested list have the same list of columns in the same order** (col1 to col4)
[image]

So far my code is really unelegant, not vectorized at all and I'm sure that can be vectorized nicely.

```
for (i in (1:length(my.list))) {
  all.fields  <- unique(names(unlist(my.list)))  # all possible fields
  loc.fields  <- names(my.list[[i]])             # fields of the current list
  miss.fields <- setdiff(all.fields, loc.fields) # missing fields to add with NA
  my.list[[i]][miss.fields] <- NA}
```

I tried with purr functions but I was unable to do something that work. Any clue or tip ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
tibble(col1 = my.list) %>%
      unnest_wider(col1)
```

---

Or with `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(my.list)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#   col1  col2  col3  col4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     3    NA
#2     1     2    NA    NA
#3     1     2    NA    NA
#4     1     2     3     4
```

---

If we want to convert back to the `list`, use `transpose` from `purrr`

```
bind_rows(my.list) %>%
     purrr::transpose
```

Comment: Awesome ! In one line of code... dplyr <3<3<3. Thank you very much !